# How to write a Node.js server if my pc's ip address changes daily

Tags: node.js, express

I am owning a Windows PC. I have written a Web application that runs fine. But the problem is my PC's IP changes periodically.  I want that application to be accessible in the network (from other pc's) without changing client side code . My client side code is in angular js.

Comment: I think this problem cannot be solved in node. You may install tools like no ip if you want to access it over the Internet. For LAN connection you may make your IP static.

Answer (score 2):

The web server of your web application cannot bind to the correct IP if it doesn't know it in advance.

You can make your IP address static by following these steps:

- In Windows, go to the Network and Sharing center
- In the left pane, choose "Change adapter settings"
- Right click your ethernet or wifi connection (the one connected to your router) and choose Properties
- Double click Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP / IPv4)

[image]

- As an IP address, choose the one your computer already has (or try another IP address starting with the first same 3 numbers, i.e. xxx.xxx.xxx.yyy)
- The default gateway is the IP address of your router
- The subnet mask is typically 255.255.255.0
- For the DNS server choose Google's 8.8.8.8 and/or your router's IP address

Answer (score 1):

You have several choices depending upon your configuration.

1. If this is the public dynamic IP you get from your ISP, you can go to your ISP (whoever you get internet service from) and upgrade your service to a static IP address so it won't change.
2. If this is the public dynamic IP you get from your ISP, you can use a dynamic DNS service to attach a hostname to your IP address and then use that hostname to access the server.  The dynamic DDNS app you put on your server will keep the DNS updated whenever your dynamic IP address changes.
3. If this is just a local IP address on your LAN (a 192.x.x.x or 10.x.x.x address), then you can pick an IP address that your router supports, but is above the range being used for DHCP and set that computer to use that IP address and not DHCP.  In Windows, you can go to the networking configuration and choose the IP address instead of using DHCP.  Then, the IP address won't ever change.  It is important that you pick an address outside the range used for DHCP to avoid any conflicts.  On my own LAN where the router is allocating addresses like 192.168.0.x, I manually assign addresses like 192.168.1.250.

Answer (score 0):

This is something that your router handles through a protocol known as [DHCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol). Basically, the answer is to keep your IP from changing.

Many routers allow you to reserve an IP for certain MAC addresses. I would recommend that you access your router over your local network and work with the GUI it provides to try to configure this... if you're successful, then your IP will no longer change, and problem solved :-) If it's not intuitive, then of course refer to the documentation for your router.